# Searchview don't remove the view with recyclerview after do a search

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, loader, android-cursor

I have implemented a searchView with a recyclerview. Looks fine, but sometimes (is completly random) don't remove the search view after press back button in the device or in the toolbar, and this remain overlay with the main screen.

I attached a screenshot to see the behaviour

[image]

Some help will be aprreciate!

This is my code in the searchview:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView sv = new SearchView(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
        MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, sv);

        sv.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.type_search));
        sv.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                cursorFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, AllContacts.this);
                return false;
            }
        });
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }
```

And this is how I do the search with the cursor:

```
 @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (cursorFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(cursorFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        String select = "((" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND (" + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 ))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create new pojo class containing the result of the search and adapter object in onQueryTextChange. And pass the search result as a parameter to the adapter.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide me some code of how to do this, please. I'm something new in android

Comment: is no way to clean the screen before do a new search here?  if (cursorFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(cursorFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }

Comment: you can clear the list before adding result to the list

Comment: how can I do this? But his, clean the duplicate items in the screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code

```
search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);

    search.requestFocus();

    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            serachEventList.clear();
            if(newText.equals(""))
            {
                eventsAdapter = new EventsAdapter(eventsArrayList,EventScreen.this);
                list_events.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(EventScreen.this));
                list_events.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
            }

            else
            {
                for(int i=0; i<eventsArrayList.size();i++)
                {
                    if(eventsArrayList.get(i).getEventname().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase().toString().trim()) || eventsArrayList.get(i).getTime().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase().toString().trim()) || eventsArrayList.get(i).getDay().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase().toString().trim()) || eventsArrayList.get(i).getLecturer().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase().toString().trim()) || eventsArrayList.get(i).getDescription().trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(newText.toLowerCase().toString().trim()))
                    {
                        serachEventList.add(eventsArrayList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                eventsAdapter = new EventsAdapter(serachEventList,EventScreen.this);
                list_events.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(EventScreen.this));
                list_events.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
            }


            return true;
        }
    });
```